# Should we always specify an ID attribute in HTML?

Tags: html

From https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp:

> In HTML5, the id attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).

I'm making a browser-based application for internal use, which in one of the pages there is no CSS or JavaScript referring to any element of the page - just tables.

**Should I still specify the id attribute for the elements though there is no (not yet) need to use it?** Or it is just best practice to put id'entifiers for future use?

Comment: `ID ` is meant to identify element uniquely either in javascript or css or any other framework. So if you are not targetting the elements you don't need to give ids, But for your understanding you can give meaningful `ids` for code readability.

Comment: No need to make the page heavier (larger in number of bytes) than is necessary. Just use IDs when you need them. As the question is currently worded, it probably stands a good chance of being closed as "Primarily opinion-based"

Comment: No, they don’t need to go on everything and it’s not good practice to put them on everything. *However*, they are usable as link targets (like the earlier `<a name>`), so consider putting them on things people might want to link to.

Comment: @Ryan That's very useful! Like you said, I'd consider to add some for direct link sharing!

Comment: This reminds me a bit on YAGNI: [You are not gonna need it](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html). It may improve readability, but it may also puzzle other people. Later, once you really need the ids, maybe you will give other names than you would give today, as your understanding has changed.

Comment: Another reason to avoid adding an `id` if you don't need it: another dev might make a component with an `id` not knowing you made a component with the same `id`. When both get included in the same page, the page is no longer valid because one page cannot have two of the same `id` values. This is very important when making a SPA with 100+ components.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Only put required **elements** or **attributes** in HTML.

You do not need to put ID attribute if it is not required, and you can always add ID attribute whenever required.

Keeping only required elements in html will make it easy to read, clean, low on size and hence improves performance and speed.

Comment: What do you mean by “required” here? Required by the HTML spec, meaning that leaving them out would break validation? Or required by the needs of your current application? I would agree with the second one, but strongly disagree with the first one (for obvious reasons).

Comment: @Janus Yes, only put those that are required by the needs of your current application.

Answer (score 12):

IDs are useful if you want to perform end-to-end testing with a framework like Protractor since it is very easy to select the particular element you want.  This is not necessary, however, because of CSS attribute selectors.  You can select on parts of the CSS class in the DOM, even without an ID being present.

Does the ID make it *easier*?  Sure, but is it required for displaying a page?  No.

Comment: In addition to that, IMHO relying on IDs for testing is problematic, because you may have to change the ID for some reason, then the tests will break. What I have found to be more reliable is to add special CSS classes for testing (like `class="uitest-contactlist"`) and use that. That way the tests get their own, separate spaces of IDs, and are better isolated from changes to the HTML.

Comment: @sleske consider using attributes instead of classes: `uitest="contactlist"`.

Comment: @Tibos: Good point. However, this only works if both your frontend technology and your testing tool supports custom attributes (most do, but not all).

Comment: @Tibos Should be using a data attribute (e.g. `data-uitest`) rather than a nonstandard (and technically invalid) attribute.

Comment: @sleske I like your solution.  People do not take advantage of CSS enough, it can be very powerful.  Just falling back to Javascript all the time is so wasteful.

Answer (score 5):

No need to add IDs if you're not going to use them. It will just add extra bytes to your website to load. I don't see why would you think you need them, the quoted text you added to your question doesn't say you should use them, it just says they CAN be used on any element.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not necessary. It is required only when you have to access any form control uniquely on a web page.

Comment: Depends upon your need .If u want to identify later then you should go for it.

Comment: That's incorrect. An `id` is never "required". Form elements can be referenced by a number of other means, such as their `name` attribute (which they do have to have if they will be submitting their form data), their element type, their position within the HTML, etc.